# best and secure way to authenticate user in php application

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I need to know how secure is my user authentication code that I am using in my php applications.

This is my login check function

```
// Is Login
//*********************************************************************************
public function isLogin()
{
    $validation = new Validation();

    if(!$validation->isEmpty($_SESSION["AdminId"]) && !$validation->isEmpty($_SESSION["AdminUsername"]) && !$validation->isEmpty($_SESSION["AdminName"]))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have a authenticate file which i call from top of every user account's page which is as under

```
if (!$admin->isLogin())
{
    header("Location: index.php?type=warning&msg=" .urlencode(ADMIN_INVALID_LOGIN));
    exit();
}
```

The session values for example Adminusername is the actual username of the admin, adminname is the alphabetical name of the admin and adminid is the record id from mysql table such as $_SESSION["Adminusername"] = administrator though i am storing this value after encypting it.

I need to know is this a secure method to just store the values and check for them or I need to have some kind of advance functionality to make it more secure such as salt or time check etc.

I would appreciate your suggestions and feedbacks. If possible, your authenticate code / class.

Thanks in advance.
Amardeep Singh

Comment: Maybe better for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: You better should send message id in url instead of actual message text, this way you would not have to worry about encoding and message length as url length has its maximum length limit and it can be easily reached if you send whole message in url.

Comment: @buksy - hi, i think u misunderstood my question. I am not concerned about the message rather a secure way about how to check whether a user is login or not.

Comment: Yes, I know, I'm just pointing on what else you could improve in your script (thats why I comment and not answer the question)

Answer (score 0):

use session regenerate id to get a new ID in every request, so u can prevent session hijacking .. read this manual : http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php

Answer (score 0):

> I am storing this value after encypting it

I don't understand... Why do you crypt your AdministratorName?

As you surely know, the user cannot manipulate his session as he wants, because the session is on the serverSide and your code decide what to write into session-data. 
I think, salting or timechecking do not raise your security-level.

Because HTTP is stateless, each session is identified by a id, which ist mostly saved in a cookie on the client side. Each of your request to this server contains this SID, because it's the only way your server could identify a visitor.

If you use HTTP-Transport, your data (end also your SID) is sent through the internet without encryption. So a hacker could read your SessionID and take over your Session (which contains logged in User-Data). To prevent this, you can force HTTPS connection for logged in users.

If you have the possibility to switch all your pages to https-only, do it. If you must switch between http and https (for example https only if user is loggedin) it becomes really difficult to guarante security!

Comment: What would you suggest then to make my authentication secure? Please let me know

Comment: I don't know your situation and how secure this area needs to be. Many application ignore this security risk, because it could be a quiet big task to grap a SID and the hacker doesn't know, if a session even contains a logged in user or not.

If it doesn't matter for you, configure the server to only deliver HTTPS requests.